# Making sense of a gradient for solving an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, vector-analysis, biology, vector-lattices

Consider a random lattice where the position of each vertex $i$ is governed by
$$
\eta \frac{d \mathbf{x}_i}{dt}=\mathbf{F}_i(t),
$$
where $\mathbf{F}_i(t)$ denotes the total force acting on vertex $i$ at time $t$. This is known in epithelial biology as the vertex model.

In this [research paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4052277/pdf/main.pdf), $\mathbf{F}_i$ is explicitly given as
$$
\mathbf{F}_i=\sum_{\alpha} \left(-K (A_\alpha(t) -A^{(0)})\nabla_iA_\alpha(t)-\Gamma P_\alpha(t) \nabla_i P_\alpha(t)  \right)-\sum_j\Lambda \nabla_il_{ij}(t),
$$
where $K,A^{(0)},\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are constants, $A_\alpha$ and $P_\alpha$ are the area and perimeter of cell (face between edges) $\alpha$ and $l_{ij}$ is the length of the cell edge (or bond) shared by vertices $i$ and $j$. $\nabla_i$ denotes the gradient operator evaluated at $\mathbf{x}_i$.

My question is: given such $\mathbf{F}_i$, how can I solve the first ODE (via Euler's method, for example)? Shouldn't I need to have $A_\alpha, P_\alpha$ and $l_{ij}$ written explicitly in terms of $\mathbf{x}_i$? Can I even do this?

I'm missing something but I'm not quite sure what it is. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: The paper suggests using the "forward Euler discretization". It is unclear how you can evaluate the gradients.

Comment: Exactly. Well, since the cells are polygons, I thought of dividing them in triangles, calculating the area (for example) depending on other $\mathbf{x}_j$'s and writing the entire system of coupled ODEs in this manner, but it might be excessive work..

Comment: How will you evaluate the gradients ?

Comment: I'm not sure at this moment. I thought about a simpler case, where we have one rectangle cell, where $A_\alpha=xy$. Then $\nabla_i A_\alpha =(y,x)|_{\mathbf{x}_i}$ and I'm done. Instead of using $x$ and $y$ I could use the coordinates of two other $\mathbf{x}_j$'s.

Comment: It all seems much simpler the way they put it, that's why I think I might be missing something. Look at page 5 of this paper, for example: http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/127202/8/vertex-model-inference.pdf